# where clause not working in firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use where clause in flutter but it is returning null though data is there in firestore. Here is my code:

```
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchInitialBatch() async {
    return (await Firestore.instance
            .collection("videos")
            .where("category", isEqualTo: category)
            .orderBy("url")
            .limit(3)
            .getDocuments())
        .documents;
  }
```

Here is screenshot of firestore:[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERhbo.png)

What is missing in it?

Comment: There is not much we can say here because we can't see the value of `category`, and we can't see your database.  So we don't know for sure if your query actually would return the documents you're thinking of.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, i have added screenshot of firestore table, even with category hardcoded it is throwing null in return..

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the name of the collection, so we don't know if that matches either.  I suggest providing a screenshot that shows both collection and document, and also hard coding the value of `category`.  You should also show the code you're using to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the that fields do not have any space or unnecessary character messing up the query. Secondly, try to invert the order of the statement and see if it work do it like below.

You can even delete each field and create them again to see if will works. Either than that I do not see that you done something wrong, for me is more like is reading something blank from the firebase itself on the fields.

```
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchInitialBatch() async {
   return (awaitFirestore.instance.collection("videos")
   .orderBy('url').limit(3).where("category",isEqualTo: category).
   getDocuments()).documents;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried this and found out orderBy and where clause wasn't able to work together. Error solved after removing orderBy, any specific reason for that??

Comment: I have a code like your one but am using stream. Am just suprized that you said that. 
```
 Stream<List<OrderModel>> getOrdersByUser(String uid) {
    return _db.collection(_collectionOrders).orderBy('date', descending: true).where('buyerID', isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapShot) => snapShot.documents
        .map((document) => OrderModel.fromDocument(document) )
        .toList()  );
  }
  ```